# Receiver xbee receiving data while the Transmitter is powered off?

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee, c

My receiver xbee is receiving data even if the transmitter is disconnected , so if i am sending the string hello world , the receiver will repeat this string .

```
void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hello");
    delay(1000);
}


void loop() {
     if(Serial.available()>0){
         Serial.print((char)Serial.read());
     }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Gerben there is no question there is a problem

Answer (score 1):

As @Garben mentioned, we do not know what is your question, problem or whatever...
Provide some more information about wiring. I looked at your question 5 mins and still can't get what is wrong...

What are you doing here??? Sending from Arduino+XBEE to another Arduino+XBEE???

```
void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hello");
    delay(1000);
}
```

Here you are resending what you got

```
void loop() {
     if(Serial.available()>0){
         Serial.print((char)Serial.read());
     }
}
```

So what is your problem? Or is this all your code???
Arduino has to have

```
void setup(){
//Set up your Arduino here
}
void loop(){
//Code here will run over and over and over...
}
```